# Sharepoint workflow remains "in progress" despite all actions being complete

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

We have several workflows, all are default Sharepoint workflows - approval / feedback etc.

Once all actions have been completed (and marked as so), the status of the document workflow remains "In Progress".

I have found several mentions of this on the web - but no solutions.

Any assistance will be extremely helpful - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the library and recreated and the problem has gone away.